# How can I create multiple dynamic components in multiple sections on a single page? Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to create 4 separate div inside a page and the content of each div comes from a separate component. So far I had successfully rendered all 4 on a single page using Component Factory however the thing I'm trying to achieve is:
First component can be static as it's the initial page and there are buttons in the first component, when I click a button in the first component I want the second div to appear next to it (containing a few buttons), and when clicking on a button on the second div the third div should appear next to it. So far what I did is this.

I created 4 separate components named block0, block1, block2 and block3 under a component named dynamic component.
I then simply kept the block 1 selector inside the HTML of dynamic component(dynamic.component.html)
here's what I did:

```
<app-block0 (notify)="onGroupReq($event)"></app-block0>
<ng-container #block1></ng-container>
<ng-container #block2></ng-container>
<ng-container #block3></ng-container>
```

I then created an event emitter in block0Component(this is actually my approach but I'm happy to change it if I get any suggestions along the way).
I was able to render the next block(Block1Component) on click on an element in block0 however since block1's selector is not there in dynamic component's HTML file, I'm stuck.

It it made any sense please suggest me what should I try any better approach.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do following steps:

1. Create a page which will work as a parent page. (Let's say
   Dashboard or Homepage)
2. Create 4 components which need to be
       rendered on DashboardPage. Use selector in those components. Also,
       export those classes.  ex. A selector is **map**, and a component is
       MapComponent.
3. In Dashboard HTML include that selector which will
   work as a child. ex. `<map></map>`

Like that you can do for all other components as well.

Comment: If I include selectors for the 4 components in the dashboard, they'll simply render, but I need to stop that from happening. I need to add them dynamically on click.

Comment: A button click can have a flag and if it's value is changed load second component. You can use a hidden attribute in this case with that flag check. Add those in a second component tag.

Comment: Not sure hidden attribute will be a good idea because of browser support issues with IE10 and earlier.

Comment: Finally using what you suggested and it works absolutely fine.. thank you so much

Comment: I'm stuck again somewhere and tried asking the community but it seems that ppl only like to down vote without giving any reason, was just wondering if you know the answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155119/angular5-not-able-to-load-dialog-with-data-when-calling-the-dialog-from-marker-d